# Query to Oracle DB for a data within a time range for a year

Tags: oracle, date, select, oracle11g, range

I am using Oracle DB version - **Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production.**

I am trying to fetch data from an Audit table from a time range - like :

```
Select * from AUDIT_TABLE where time > '13/02/2018 19:00:00' and time < '14/02/2018 07:00:00'
```

Here, the time column datatype is `DATE`.

But, business want this data for last 1 year. So, we need to run this kind of data with last 1 year date.

We got two ideas:
1) We can write a proc and pass the start date and end and query in db for 365 time and may be write the result in a file/temp db

2) Query the whole year data and put filter in excel.

But, it seems both the ideas will consume much effort and not very good solution. Is there any way to do this quickly.

Say, our data set is like :

```
ID  TIMESTAMP       USER_ID
1   09/07/2012 09:52:05 XXXXXXX
2   09/07/2012 09:57:06 YYYYY
3   09/10/2012 10:49:10 ZZZZZZ
4   09/25/2012 05:58:37 ABCCC
5   09/25/2012 06:00:30 XXXXXXX
6   09/25/2012 06:07:03 YYYYY
7   09/25/2012 13:38:18 ZZZZZZ
8   09/26/2012 12:12:59 ABCCC
9   09/27/2012 11:01:29 XXXXXXX
10  09/28/2012 05:59:47 YYYYY
11  09/28/2012 06:06:58 ZZZZZZ
12  09/28/2012 06:07:28 ABCCC
13  10/03/2012 14:04:48 XXXXXXX
14  10/06/2012 12:44:08 YYYYY
15  10/09/2012 05:59:47 ZZZZZZ
16  10/09/2012 06:03:35 ABCCC
17  10/09/2012 06:04:04 XXXXXXX
18  10/09/2012 06:15:28 YYYYY
19  10/10/2012 06:54:21 ZZZZZZ
20  10/11/2012 07:54:18 ABCCC
21  10/11/2012 08:16:41 XXXXXXX
22  10/11/2012 08:23:08 YYYYY
23  10/11/2012 09:44:42 ZZZZZZ
24  10/11/2012 11:46:30 ABCCC
25  10/12/2012 06:32:33 XXXXXXX
```

and we want only the resultset present with 19:00 to 07:00 and this would be for a year of data in a single result set and return something like :

```
ID  TIMESTAMP       USER_ID
4   09/25/2012 05:58:37 ABCCC
5   09/25/2012 06:00:30 XXXXXXX
6   09/25/2012 06:07:03 YYYYY
10  09/28/2012 05:59:47 YYYYY
11  09/28/2012 06:06:58 ZZZZZZ
12  09/28/2012 06:07:28 ABCCC
15  10/09/2012 05:59:47 ZZZZZZ
16  10/09/2012 06:03:35 ABCCC
17  10/09/2012 06:04:04 XXXXXXX
18  10/09/2012 06:15:28 YYYYY
19  10/10/2012 06:54:21 ZZZZZZ
25  10/12/2012 06:32:33 XXXXXXX
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want the same time range for every day in the last year, up to the current date - all in one result set? But only that 12-hour window? (And what about records at exactly 19:00 or 07:00 - should one of those be >= or <= ?)

Comment: Yes, should be >= and <=; so ideally we should take the time only from the date and have to run this from last year till current date

Comment: Please show sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

you may use easily `months_between` by comparing wtih `12`(months) to get the values of last one year upto current date:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM AUDIT_TABLE 
 WHERE months_between(sysdate,time)<=12
 ORDER BY time;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you really mean `time >= 19:00:00 and time < 07:00:00` (ignoring the date) you could something like:

```
select * from AUDIT_TABLE
where time >= add_months(trunc(sysdate), -12) + 19/24
and extract(hour from cast(time - 7/24 as timestamp)) >= 12
```

The first filter gets midnight this morning, goes back 12 months, then adds 19 hours to get to the start of the window you're interested in.

The second filter adjust the time by 7 hours just make the comparison easier, so the range effectively now doesn't span midnight, and extracts the hour number from that.

Quick demo:

```
with audit_table (id, time) as (
            select 1, to_date('2017-02-12 18:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select 2, to_date('2017-02-12 19:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select 3, to_date('2017-02-12 19:00:01', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select 4, to_date('2017-02-13 06:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select 5, to_date('2017-02-13 07:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select 6, to_date('2017-02-13 07:00:01', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select 7, to_date('2018-02-11 18:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select 8, to_date('2018-02-11 19:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select 9, to_date('2018-02-11 19:00:01', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select 10, to_date('2018-02-11 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select 11, to_date('2018-02-12 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select 12, to_date('2018-02-12 00:00:01', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select 13, to_date('2018-02-12 06:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select 14, to_date('2018-02-12 07:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select 15, to_date('2018-02-12 07:00:01', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
)
select * from AUDIT_TABLE
where time >= add_months(trunc(sysdate), -12) + 19/24
and extract(hour from cast(time - 7/24 as timestamp)) >= 12
/

        ID TIME               
---------- -------------------
         2 2017-02-12 19:00:00
         3 2017-02-12 19:00:01
         4 2017-02-13 06:59:59
         8 2018-02-11 19:00:00
         9 2018-02-11 19:00:01
        10 2018-02-11 23:59:59
        11 2018-02-12 00:00:00
        12 2018-02-12 00:00:01
        13 2018-02-12 06:59:59
```

If you actually want `time > 19:00:00 and time <= 07:00:00` you can adjust by another second:

```
select * from AUDIT_TABLE
where time > add_months(trunc(sysdate), -12) + 19/24
and extract(hour from cast(time - 7/24 - 1/86400 as timestamp)) >= 12

        ID TIME               
---------- -------------------
         3 2017-02-12 19:00:01
         4 2017-02-13 06:59:59
         8 2018-02-11 19:00:00
         9 2018-02-11 19:00:01
        10 2018-02-11 23:59:59
        11 2018-02-12 00:00:00
        12 2018-02-12 00:00:01
        13 2018-02-12 06:59:59
        14 2018-02-12 07:00:00
```

If you really do mean `time >= 19:00:00 and time <= 07:00:00` then you can combine the first version with an more explicit check for final second:

```
select * from AUDIT_TABLE
where time >= add_months(trunc(sysdate), -12) + 19/24
and (
  extract(hour from cast(time - 7/24 as timestamp)) >= 12
  or time - 7/24 = trunc(time)
)

        ID TIME               
---------- -------------------
         2 2017-02-12 19:00:00
         3 2017-02-12 19:00:01
         4 2017-02-13 06:59:59
         5 2017-02-13 07:00:00
         8 2018-02-11 19:00:00
         9 2018-02-11 19:00:01
        10 2018-02-11 23:59:59
        11 2018-02-12 00:00:00
        12 2018-02-12 00:00:01
        13 2018-02-12 06:59:59
        14 2018-02-12 07:00:00
```

Comment: It is working. Thanks a ton, i tried to upvote your idea, but my reputation is too low to upvote. But, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM AUDIT_TABLE 
WHERE `time` BETWEEN SYSDATE - '12' MONTH AND SYSDATE
ORDER BY `time`;
```